# Is there a way to make Timer.ScheduleAtFixedRate more accurate?

Tags: java, android, timer

I'm writing an Android app in java. Trying to make a simple rhythm game where you just tap the button on a beat. I was using a timer object with Schedule at Fixed Rate to make the button flash but then I discovered that the time is variable by a few milliseconds.

Obviously a rhythm game needs particular timing to come out right, so is it possible to make this more precise and accurate or am I barking up the wrong tree with using this method for precise timing?

Comment: "is it possible to make this more precise and accurate or am I barking up the wrong tree with using this method for precise timing?" -- you are barking up the wrong tree in terms of how you are writing the game. If you need this level of timing accuracy, you cannot use the `View` hierarchy the way you would if you were writing a to-do app. When your `Timer` is being invoked, you are then turning around and using something like `runOnUiThread()` to update your UI, and that will introduce timing instability.

Comment: Well I was trying someone else's suggestion to use a Scheduled Executor Service and that's providing better results, it appears consistent to me for the visuals. The actual input detection is on the main thread. Do you still think it will be a big issue?

Comment: As I am not writing your game, I have no way of knowing if the issue will be big or not. It *is* an issue. `runOnUiThread()` posts a message to the main application thread's work queue, and that work will only be done when the message reaches the head of the queue. Exactly how much time that will be is non-deterministic. Perhaps in your situation, it will be good enough.

Comment: Ok, I see what you're saying. I might get away with it, the game is a short project so I won't have time for full polish and it's also not resource intensive. It's working on my phone but I'll try testing it on slower devices in case they'd handle it worse.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know for Android but here is what happens for "real" Java...

A `Timer` uses `System.currentTimeMillis()` to keep track of time; this method is sensitive to system time changes (say, you run an NTP server for instance).

Which is why, if you want better precision, you use a `ScheduledExecutorService`; this relies o `System.nanoTime()`, which is a nanosecond precision counter which keeps increasing for the life of the process, even if the system time changes.

So --> try a `ScheduledExecutorService` instead.

Comment: This sorted it out for me, thanks!
Other answers are suggesting that I could still have issues with this approach but this answer definitely improved matters as it is. The caveat being that I'm running a simple game, it doesn't drain a lot of resources. Also the visuals are the only thing affected by this loop, not the game logic itself.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you don't use ScheduleAtFixedRate!!  Use a Looper and Handler.sendMessageDelayed()

Comment: And why would one _not_ want to use `.scheduleAtFixedRate()`? It Just Works(tm) (well, `ScheduledExecutorService`'s one, that is)